# Inherited control not rendered

Tags: nevron

I have a question about the `Nevron Chart Control`. I created a new and "empty" class `myNevronChart` that inherits from the `NThinChartControl` class. Then in the init event I created an instance of this class and added it to the `Page` controls collection but the form opens empty and the chart is not rendered. If I use `NThinChartControl` class instead of `myNevronChart` everything works fine and the chart renders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for a SP - the problem is that the control searches for some resources based on the assembly defining the chart control. When you override the control in your code you effectively change the assembly where the control looks for resources.